# Meu log out não funcionou corretamente

Tags: suporte, bug, status-intencional, contas-usuário

Estava logado na empresa na máquina de meu colega. Usei o SOpt e depois ao sair da empresa, fiz logout na máquina. Hoje pela manhã, quando eu abri o SOpt, já veio meu usuário, sem que eu me logasse, ou seja, como se não tivesse dado logout. O que posso fazer? Isso é sério, pois caso eu esteja em uma máquina de cyber(rua), por exemplo, posso deslogar e continuar logado. Agradeço por qualquer ajuda no que fazer.

Comment: Esse problema nunca aconteceu comigo, sempre que deslogo de uma máquina, minha sessão é encerrada em todas máquinas que estava logado, geralmente uso no serviço, em dois notebooks de casa, na casa da minha namorada e na faculdade, e nunca tive esse mesmo problema.

Comment: Tem que ver se não foi um erro atípico, se deslogou corretamente, ver se o problema é só naquela máquina, e por fim ver se isso está ocorrendo com mais algum usuário

Comment: Não guardaste a sessão no *browser*?

Comment: @JorgeB., pode ser que isso tenha ocorrido, mas não me lembro em salvar senha alguma. Isso é a primeira vez que acontece, pois até em casa eu deslogo e pronto. Aqui é que me deu esse erro e como não é a minha máquina, preciso me deslogar e logar sempre.

Comment: @pnet eu não costumo terminar a sessão nunca por isso não sei, mas quanto tenho esse tipo de problemas costuma ser porque guardei os dados no *browser*.

Comment: Em minha casa eu não termino, mas aqui na empresa preciso, pois como eu disse anteriormente, eu estou em uma máquina que não é a minha, pois ainda não possuo login na rede e etc, questões burocrática ainda e estou na máquina do meu coordenador até ter o meu login definitivo. Essa é a razão da necessidade do logout funcionar.

Comment: Quando você diz que hoje de manhã já veio o seu usuário, foi na mesma máquina da qual você deslogou ontem? Eles mudaram recentemente o sistema de login/logout, talvez agora seja por máquina.

Comment: Se você está em um computador compartilhado, lembre-se de também fazer o log-out do seu provedor de Open ID (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange, etc.). No meu caso eu sempre tenho que deslogar pelo "Stack Exchange"

Comment: O log consta que eu último logout foi hoje, 1 hora atrás. Antes disso o último tinha sido dia 11/07. Eu não sei o que pode ter ocorrido...

Comment: 1 hora atrás, é que eu consegui meu acesso aqui na empresa e desloguei da máquina do meu colega. Observei isso agora, que ao deslogar no botão log out, no canto superior direito da página SOpt, me apareceu um outro botão em baixo de LOG OUT. Se ontem esse botão apareceu, não vi e por isso acho que não completei o log out, estou correto? Eu entro sempre pelo StackoverFlow, acho não ser necessário ir a outro site, como facebook e etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você faz o logout do pt.stackoverflow.com, você está apenas finalizando a sessão dele, mas não finaliza a dos demais site, por exemplo quando eu tento deslogar, aparece isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto quer dizer que deve confirmar pelo botão "logo-ut" e também deve desconectar do "provedor", por exemplo Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange (este é o meu caso), pois se não outra pessoa pode acessar facilmente os seus sites sem precisar digitar a senha.

Recomendo acessar uma por uma (apesar de trabalhoso) para verificar.

Comment: Faltou realmente eu confirmar nesse botão de Log Out. Fiz apenas o do canto superior da tela, mas acho que ele é apenas uma chamada ao log out. A confirmação realmente me desloga e foi o que eu não fiz.